# I can't use already installed python modules

Tags: python

I'm trying, to write a script that will automate moving player for example in minecraft. I installed library (or whatever you call it) called `keyboard` but when i try to use my code it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\samcio\Desktop\py\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import keyboard
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keyboard'
```

I recently formatted my pc. I haven't got that error earlier. Path to python it `C:\Users\samcio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311`

I tried adding python to system variables:
[image]

I also tried reinstalling both python, and `keyboard` module. I don't think it is module (or library) issue, because i also have same problem with other libraries (or modules).

Comment: Would you show the commands you used to install the python packages?  Would you also show the code you use to import the libraries?

Comment: 1. pip install pynput
2. python -m pip install pynput

Comment: and 3. pip3 install pynput

Comment: You use 3 different commands?  Is `pip` the same as `pip3`?

Comment: and the code is 
import keyboard
import time

Comment: I used one, tried if it worked, if not used another, etc. When i try to install it now, it says that package is already installed.

Comment: So, after `python -m pip install keyboard`, `keyboard` is successfully installed, but in a python script `import keyboard` generates an error?

Comment: Yes, exactly sir.

Comment: How was python installed?

Comment: https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Windows platform and I believe you have some issue with `PATH`, `PYTHONPATH`, or some other system environment variable.  Hopefully someone with Windows experience will help you.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share  `where python pip` and `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"` and check whether all point to the same python installation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you are installing your modules on the same python installation as you are running your code.

If you are running your code with python file.py, then try doing python -m pip install discord

If you are running your python via python3, or py3, or otherwise (if you haven't try these alternatives), and then use that instead. You are likely using a pip that is not on the installation that you are executing your code base in.

You might be using a py launcher that's getting you in trouble too.
Try `py -3.11 -m pip install []` for the installs to see if that helps.